# Carriage return in doxygen?

Tags: documentation, vhdl, doxygen

I'm documenting my VHDL code with doxygen. I need to insert a carriage return between two lines and I'm not able to do it.

I try inserting &crarr, with return key... Nothing works! Any solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just inserting an additional blank line in between the two lines? This should work fine.
If not, could you explain what is your intention more in detail? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Did you try <br> or \n?

Comment: Thanks @albert ! It works!

Comment: Yes @Robiston, I tried an I didn't work! The other answer above is more accurate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing `<br>` or `\n` in VHDL comments a carriage return is inserted.